# what does the lsamp in "stats.ttest_1samp" stand for?

Tags: python

What does "lsamp" stand for? Abbreviation or others meaningful explaination from semantics point?

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import stats

stats.ttests_lsamp()
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the T-test for the mean of **ONE** group of scores. So it stands for 1 sample. [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html) is the documentation.

There are:

- ttest_1samp: Calculate the T-test for the mean of ONE group of scores
- ttest_ind: Calculate the T-test for the means of two independent samples of scores
- ttest_ind_from_stats: T-test for means of two independent samples from descriptive statistics
- ttest_rel: Calculate the t-test on TWO RELATED samples of scores, a and b.

You may choose whatever describes what you want to do.